# Regular expression Notepad++ OK JDK 1.6 NOK

Tags: java, regex, java-6

As part of my internship, I have to use regular expressions to parse a log file. It's Java log and I have a problem with the detection of exceptions.

In fact, my regular expression works on Notepad++ but not with Java (1.6), the matcher.find() take a very, ..., very long time, and find 0 match finally.

This is my regular expression:

```
(.*\bERROR\b.*)\r?\n((\tat|.*[Ee]xception|\t\.\.\.|\r?\n|ORA-).*\r?\n)+(^(?!.*ERROR).+)\r?\n
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you escape the \ (backslash)? Can you show the exact code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Back slash `\` is both escape character for java programming language and for regular expressions. Therefore when back slashes for regular expressions inside java (and many other programming languages) you have to duplicate the back slash.

For example write `\\s` instead of `\s` as requires syntax of regular expression.

Comment: Mind that `\t`, `\r` and `\n` can remain unescaped.

Comment: Yes, we must double slash in Java regular expression. I only write the expression to make it clearer. My problem was when declaring my object, I had forgotten MULTILINE flag.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to test your regexp, then have the corresponding String to build the java regexp object

Comment: I already try on the mentioned website, but the expression doesn't work. The problem was in the declaration of Pattern object.
Now it's working : Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of `^` character, do not forget to declare the `Pattern` object with multiline flag.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Thank you very much! Can you tell me why we should to use it ?